# Laravel 5.4 MySQL 5.6.35 - El famoso #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Creando un migración en Laravel 5.4 con MySQL 5.6
Puedo añadir una referencia externa perfectamente si es sobre el Id de otra tabla, pero no puedo añadirla sobre un indice string.

*Esta funciona bien sobre el campo Id*

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `component_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stock_component_code_code_unique` (`component_code`,`code`),
  KEY `stock_component_id_foreign` (`component_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `stock_component_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `components` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

*Pero quiero sobre el campo VARCHAR*

```
 CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `component_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stock_component_code_code_unique` (`component_code`,`code`),
  KEY `stock_component_id_foreign` (`component_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `stock_component_code_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`component_code`) REFERENCES `components` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Obtengo

> `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

¿Que puedo hacer?
No es tema de Laravel, 
El error lo obtengo en MySQL directamente.

Comment: ¿podemos ver el código de creación de la tabla `components`?

Comment: Es probable que component_code no sea KEY y por eso no le puede agregar la foreign key.. Como si lo es component_id

Comment: @Santi la solución no debe ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta, para eso dispones de la zona de respuestas un poco mas abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso de claves foráneas del tipo varchar, se puede seguir el siguiente ejemplo, en donde una reparación tiene una terminal asociada:

-en la definición de la migración, de la tabla con la clave primaria del tipo varchar (terminales), se puede definir de la siguiente manera (en este caso, código sería la clave primaria):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('terminales', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->string('codigo');
        $table->primary('codigo');  

        $table->string('direccion');
```

-en el modelo (Terminal), realizar la siguiente definición (seteando principalmente, las variables primaryKey e incrementing):

```
class Terminal extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "codigo";

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = "terminales";

    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'direccion', 'telefono', ];
```

-y por último, en la definición de la migración, de la tabla que va a instanciar a la anteriormente mencionada (reparaciones), se puede definir de la siguiente manera:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reparaciones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('clave');

        $table->string('id_terminal');
        $table->foreign('id_terminal')->references('nro')->on('terminales');
```

Saludos